# give line break in django form.init data

Tags: django, django-forms, textarea

I have a django form as given below.

```
class SampleForm(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

When I create a form object i want to initialize the 'message' textarea with a long paragraph.
But I need to split the text at certain positions. So I tried to put '\n' and then '< br />'. Both seems not working!. How can this be achieved in django form?. welcome for any suggestion.

Edit:
this is the form initialization code:

```
 def sample_view(request):
     initial = {'message':'''Hello,\nThis is how my message \n look like. '''}
     form = SampleForm(initial=initial)
```

Comment: '\n' should work. Put your code how you do this please

Comment: But '\n' not working. line breaks when it reaches textarea width and instead of new line it shows some space.

Comment: What does your rendered response look like?

Comment: textarea filled with message, line break happens when text reaches the  text area's right side border. inside text area string '\n' is not shown!.

Comment: Could you post it as is? '\n' should not show, it's meaningful in Python not in HTML.

Comment: Ooz.very sorry for my mistake. '\n' will work. My server side code was replacing all newlines with space. It worked when I removed that line. Thanks to San4ez and okm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'\n' will do the trick here...